# Debug models with the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure why this is happening:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > User.column_names
 => ["id", "user_name", "email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at", "register_key", "culminated", "remember_token", "register_token_created_at", "profile_image", "licence_image", "first_name", "last_name", "nearest_town"] 
2.0.0p247 :002 > user1 = User.create(user_name: 'james', email: 'james@killbots.com', first_name:'jj', last_name:'jj', nearest_town:'mordor')
 => #<User id: nil, user_name: "james", email: "james@killbots.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, register_key: nil, culminated: nil, remember_token: nil, register_token_created_at: nil, profile_image: nil, licence_image: nil, first_name: "jj", last_name: "jj", nearest_town: "mordor"> 
2.0.0p247 :003 > user1.update(user_name: 'killo')
 => false
```

Rather than a solution, how would you go about debugging this problem from the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `User` record is not saved, probably because of failed validation.
You should check its validity with:

```
user1.valid?
```

and show errors:

```
user1.errors.full_messages
```

Answer (score 2):

If you notice:

```
2.0.0p247 :002 > user1 = User.create(user_name: 'james', email: 'james@killbots.com', first_name:'jj', last_name:'jj', nearest_town:'mordor')
 => #<User id: nil, user_name: "james", email: "james@killbots.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, register_key: nil, culminated: nil, remember_token: nil, register_token_created_at: nil, profile_image: nil, licence_image: nil, first_name: "jj", last_name: "jj", nearest_town: "mordor">
```

**User record (user1) was not created at all. User id is nil. You must be having some failed validations.** If the record would have been successfully created in the database then your user `id` would never be `nil` as its the **primary key**.

Try with **User.create!** instead so you know that why the record was not created, you will get the exact exception raised. For example:

> 2.0.0p247 :002 > user1 = **User.create!**(user_name: 'james', email: 'james@killbots.com', first_name:'jj', last_name:'jj',
>   nearest_town:'mordor')

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your object is not valid. As Kirti pointed out it has not been persisted to the database as no primary key id has been returned. Checking the validity of your object would give you more information on what is up with your object. Checkout rails guides for a breakdown of [validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: pry is also a really good option for debugging, but I don't think you need it for this.